# PullRefreshIndicator does not disappear after Refreshing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, pull-to-refresh

I have migrated from ***Accompanist SwipeRefresh*** (deprecated) to ***PullRefreshIndicator*** which is now the default indicator for Compose.

The first issue I encountered was PullRefreshIndicator overlapping other components, but I managed this by using zIndex as explained on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74848769/7839518).

The problem now is that the indicator is not disappearing/hidden after a refresh as illustrated below.

[image]

I have narrowed the issue down to the *state type* passed to `rememberPullRefreshState()`.

```
val state by viewModel.fixturesState.collectAsState()
val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(
        refreshing = state.isLoading/isRefreshing,
        onRefresh = { viewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.OnSwipeRefresh) }
    )
```

In my [ViewModel](https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/InstantScore/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/com/uxstate/instantscore/presentation/screens/home_screen/HomeViewModel.kt) I have two states i.e. **`isLoading`** and **`isRefreshing`** . State *isLoading* is triggered when the data is loading while State isRefreshing is activated as an Event when the user pulls down to refresh. The *isLoading* state is toggled between false and true by flow emission in relation to the data fetch. The *isRefreshing* state is switched to true following a refresh action by the user and is switched back to false from inside the method that is fetching the data.

This is the [link to HomeScreen](https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/InstantScore/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/com/uxstate/instantscore/presentation/screens/home_screen/HomeScreen.kt).

If I pass ***isLoading*** the indicator is correctly hidden after the refresh.

```
 val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(
        refreshing = state.isLoading,
        onRefresh = { viewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.OnSwipeRefresh) }
    )
```

However, if I pass ***isRefreshing*** the indicator doesn't go away after the refresh.

```
val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(
        refreshing = state.isRefreshing,
        onRefresh = { viewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.OnSwipeRefresh) }
    )
```

I could could leave the code this way (*stick with isLoading*) and move on but I notice some inconsistencies because everytime there is loading, the indicator briefly appears and then goes away which is not desirable for UI/UX.

Anybody with any leads to rectify this issue please help. I am using `Material 3 [1.1.0-alpha04]` and `Compose Version 1.3`

Comment: Off-topic: Friendly advice, if you wanna use compose for production, do it after, at least, 5 years. There is a very long and disturbing way until compose makes it. I started using it, APIs are really ugly and there are lots of restrictions on UI.

Comment: Keep your advice to yourself. this is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in compose 1.4.0-alpha03, according to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/248274004. A delay of 1 second is really long. It is possible to fix it without delay:

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
fun PullRefreshBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    refreshing: Boolean,
    onRefresh: () -> Unit = {},
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    // The LaunchedEffect is needed to fix the hiding of the indicator: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/248274004
    // Without this workaround the indicator would be visible even if the loading finished
    var isRefreshingWorkaround by remember { mutableStateOf(refreshing) }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = refreshing) {
        isRefreshingWorkaround = refreshing
    }
    val state = rememberPullRefreshState(isRefreshingWorkaround, onRefresh)
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.pullRefresh(state),
    ) {
        content()
        PullRefreshIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
            refreshing = isRefreshingWorkaround,
            state = state,
            contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up introducing a delay of 1000 milliseconds before setting refreshing to false:

```
fun refresh() = refreshScope.launch {
    refreshing = true
    viewModel.goDoStuff()
    delay(1000L)
    refreshing = false
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is something. It will definitely work. Thx Mark